# SeekToCurrentErrorHandler with RetryableException handling (and not NotRetryableException)

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Actual `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` has the ability to add not retryable exception, meaning all exception are retryable, except the initial one, and added X, Y, Z exceptions.

Stupid question : Is there a simple way to do the opposite : all exception are not retryable, except X', Y', Z'...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible see this configuration method of that class:

```
/**
 * Set an exception classifications to determine whether the exception should cause a retry
 * (until exhaustion) or not. If not, we go straight to the recoverer. By default,
 * the following exceptions will not be retried:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link DeserializationException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MessageConversionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MethodArgumentResolutionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link NoSuchMethodException}</li>
 * <li>{@link ClassCastException}</li>
 * </ul>
 * All others will be retried.
 * When calling this method, the defaults will not be applied.
 * @param classifications the classifications.
 * @param defaultValue whether or not to retry non-matching exceptions.
 * @see BinaryExceptionClassifier#BinaryExceptionClassifier(Map, boolean)
 * @see #addNotRetryableExceptions(Class...)
 */
public void setClassifications(Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> classifications, boolean defaultValue) {
```

So, to make everything not-retryable you need to provide a default value as `false`.
The map should then container those exception you'd like to have retryable with the value for keys as `true`.

Comment: I see, I must use ```setClassifications``` with the STCEH instead of ```addNotRetryableException``` right ?

Comment: Right. According your requirement, you'd like to override default for all other exceptions. That is the only way to change that default to `false`.